# Data about default rates of H1B visa holders on their past student loans?

Tags: data-request, usa, data.gov, finance

For international students in the US, I would like to know if there are any specific default statistics about international students. I’m mostly interested in looking at defaults that occur when the borrower is no longer a student and is employed (on a H1B visa for example).